# Allocating a char pointer array

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, char

I've got a number of files that I am reading the contents into a char array, I would like to store the contents I read from each file in an array of characters so that I could access the separate character arrays (file contents) by index, I am not sure of the syntax on how to do this.

My understanding is that I need to set each of the memory addresses in my patterns array to one memory address per char array; to the char array stored in patternData but I do not know how to set this. What is the syntax that I am missing that I need to get this to happen?

What I've tried

I would have thought that If I was storing a type of `char*` then I would need a type `char**` to store the separate arrays of char arrays.

I would access a `char*` by using the following notation to set the memory address of the pattern index to

```
&patterns[INDEX] = &pData;
```

However this does not work. There is a plethora of "char pointer array" questions but I'm not sure of the correct way to do this simple assignment of `pData` to an index of patterns.

```
char *tData;
int tLength;
char *pData;
int pLength;

char **patterns;

void ReadFromFile(FILE *f, char **data, int *length) //This is what is passed into function


    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            FILE *f;
            char fileName[1000];
            sprintf(fileName, "file%d.txt", i);
            f = fopen(fileName, "r");
            if (f == NULL)
                return 0;

            ReadFromFile(f, &pData, &pLength); //works to here, contents of file assigned to pData
            fclose(f);

            &patterns[i - 1] = &pData;

        }

        return 0;

    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't it read `patterns[i - 1] = pData;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is incorrect:

```
&patterns[i - 1] = &pData;
```

You are trying to assign to the result of the "take an address" operator, which is not possible because it's not an lvalue.

The assignment should be as follows:

```
patterns[i - 1] = pData;
```

but you need to allocate `patterns` before you do this. You can use

```
patterns = malloc(sizeof(char*)*5);
```

or simply declare `patterns` to be an array of five:

```
char *patterns[5];
```

This assumes that your `ReadFromFile` function allocates a `char*`, and assigns it to the address pointed to by `pData`. Note that you need to `free` all pointers that were obtained through `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read particularly carefully, but it strikes me as odd that you're taking the reference of patterns when it's a **.  This is in the line:

```
&patterns[i-1] = &pData;
```

Comment: Sorry I think thats a line written with inherent confusion, I basically need to assign the memory address at that patterns index to the address of pData