# Reading from a text file that contains a list

Tags: c

The purpose of the program is to read a text file that contains a list of 55 authors and titles of books. The format of the list goes (author name, booktitle). I can use malloc, strlen, strtok, and strcopy. So far I got the program to read out the names of the authors but I am stuck on how to get the program to read the titles of the books.How would I get the program to read the titles of the books from the text file? I know that there are errors in this code so please be kind .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void loadBookName(char* filename, char* authorName[55], char* bookName[55]);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  //Create two arrays each with length 55
  char* authorName[55];
  char* bookName[55];

  //Ask the user for the name of the file
  char fileName[30];
  //Insert your code here
  printf("Please enter the name of the file\n");
  scanf("%s", fileName);

  //Call the method loadBookName
  loadBookName(fileName, authorName, bookName);

return 0;

//Print the two arrays to test if the two arrays were correctly loaded with the data
int i = 0;
printf("%-30s%-40s\n", "Author", "Book");
for (i = 0; i < 55; i++) {
    printf("%-30s%-40s\n", authorName[i], bookName[i]);
}

}

   /*
  loadBookName method
  This method is responsible for:
   1. Take a file containing a book name and the author name as input
   2. Open the file       
   3. Read the information in the file and store it in two arrays: authorName, bookName
   4. Return the two arrays to the main method.
   */
  void loadBookName(char* filename, char* authorName[55], char* bookName[55])
  {
   int i;
   char string_array[80];
   const char comma[2] = ",";
   //Open the file
   FILE *fp;
   fp = fopen(filename, "r");
   if (fp == NULL)
   {
       printf("Failed to open file\n");
       exit(1);
   }

   for (i=0; i<55; i++)
      {
       fgets(string_array, 80, fp);
       authorName[i] = strtok(string_array, comma);
       printf("%s\n", *authorName);
      }





      //Close the file
      fclose(fp);
      }
```

when I run the program in terminal it asks me to enter the filename (books.txt). Then when I enter the file name, the program prints a list of 55 authors.

Comment: Could you add a sample of the data?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: `authorName[i] = strtok(string_array, comma);` : address of part of `string_array` (of local variable) set to `authorName[i]`. you need `strdup`(allocate and copy).

Comment: You may want to check, I think this exact question has been answered in the past few days. See [**Memory allocation for char array**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32442600/memory-allocation-for-char-array/32443987#32443987)

Comment: the main() function, about 10 lines into the body, has the statement: `return 0;`  so none of the following lines will ever by executed.   Please consistently indent the code.  (never use tabs for indenting as each word processor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set differently.)  Suggest indent 4 spaces after every opening brace '{' and un-indent before every closing brace '}'.   The suggested 4 spaces is visibile even on variable width fonts and does not eat up the whole page width when the code is well nested

Comment: the compiler, which should always have all warnings enabled, will output (at least) 2 warnings: 1) parameter 'argc' not used 2) parameter 'argv[]' not used.  Fix all the warnings, then repost the code

Comment: when handling an error returned from a system function, use `perror()` rather than `printf()`  Then the output will be to stderr rather than stdout and the system error message will be printed.

Comment: there are a number of 'magic' numbers in the code.  Magic numbers make the code harder to understand, harder to modify and leave us all guessing what those 'magic' numbers actually mean.   Suggest #define MEAINGFUL_NAME (number)  or create a enum definition that contains meaningful names and those numbers

Comment: the code is allowing for two fields to be read, each a max of 55 characters (a total of 110 characters + delimiters)  however, the max line length is on 80 characters.   Which is the correct condition?

Comment: this statement: `printf("%-30s%-40s\n", authorName[i], bookName[i]);` does not match up with the definitions of the two fields `authorName` and `bookName' which are defined as 55 characters each.  The mismatch means the output can be truncated or otherwise corrupted

Comment: I see I made a slight error in my prior comments about the width of the fields authorName and bookName.   These are actually arrays of 55 char pointers.  However, no memory has actually been allocated to contain the actual author and book names.  I.E. the function malloc will need to be called twice for each line read from input file..  Natually all those allocated memory areas will need to be passed to `free()` before exiting the program

Comment: this line: `authorName[i] = strtok(string_array, comma);` will only set a pointer, on every loop, to the same place in the input buffer.  so all the pointers will be to the same place, which will contain the value from the last line read from the file.  suggest using malloc(); strcpy(); or use strdup()

Comment: the call to fgets(), will in most cases,  end the input buffer with "\n\0"  so when you fix the code to also input the bookName, will need to replace the '\n' with '\0'

Answer (score 0):

Simple way of separating strings with strlcpy:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int 
main(void )
{
    size_t i = 1;
    char *authorName, *bookName;
    const char *a_line_in_a_file  = 
         "Lewis Carroll,The Hunting of the Snark";
    const char *title = a_line_in_a_file;
    while ( *title != ','){
        title++;
        i++;}
    authorName = malloc(i);
    bookName = malloc(strlen(title));
    title++;
#if __BSD_VISIBLE
    strlcpy(bookName, title, strlen(title) + 1);
    strlcpy(authorName, a_line_in_a_file, i);
#else
    snprintf(bookName, strlen(title) + 1, "%s", title);
    snprintf(authorName, i, "%s", a_line_in_a_file);
#endif 
    printf("%-30s%-40s\n", authorName, bookName);
   free(authorName);
   free(bookName);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I do not find the function: `strlcpy()` on the ubuntu linux 14.04 system

Comment: Replacing with the more portable snprintf maybe fix like : snprintf(bookName, strlen(title) + 1, "%s", title);   snprintf(authorName, i, "%s", a_line_in_a_file);

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a compiler in front of me, so excuse the compilation error if it has any. But I think you can try something as below, within your existing code:

**UPDATED:**

After comments, I've updated one line. This is compiled and working.

Assumptions: User need to take care of error-handling e.g. file not present, file unable to open, buffer overflows etc.

```
    char *token;

    for (i=0; i<55; i++)
    {
        //fgets(string_array, 80, fp);
        //This will take care in case if lines are less than 55
        if(!fgets(string_array, 80, fp))
            break;


        //Get the author
        token = strtokstring_array, comma);
        authorName[i] = token;  // or use string copy functions

        //Get book name
        while( token != NULL ) 
        {
            printf( " %s\n", token );    //this shall print author name
            token = strtok(NULL, comma);
            bookName[i] = token;
            printf( " %s\n", token );    //this shall print book name

            //EDIT: This is additional line after suggestions
            token = strtok(NULL, comma);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I attempted the code but it failed to open the file

Comment: cannot be assured that the file has 55lines, so suggest replacing the `for (i=0; i<55; i++)` with `while fgets( string_array, 80, fp) )`  and perform the line counting within the loop, so if input file is greater than 55 lines, the bookName and authorName arrays will not be overrun

Comment: this code assumes the input file is already successfully opened and it fails to save the authorName.   Also, all the authorName and bookName char pointers will point into the `stringArray`, so will all be wrong except the last one and stringArray is a local variable on the stack of the sub function, so will be invalid after exiting that function.   suggest using strdup() to place unique pointers into the authorName and bookName arrays